# MySQL - use round() in a group by function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, rounding

In MySQL, how would I use the round() function inside the group by function? Example of what I've tried:

```
Table 1
a     b
1.3   5
1.4   6
2.7   8
3.0   9

Select round(a,0), avg(b)
from Table1
group by round(a,0)
```

Ideally this would give me an output like this:

```
round(a,0)    avg(b)
1             5.5
3             8.5
```

But this does not work. Any ideas?

I am using Sequel Pro on a Mac

Comment: FWIW, I am using Sequel Pro on a Mac

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your "does not work" mean?

Comment: Good point, answer is it basically just runs forever. I'm not sure if I'm not being patient enough because it is a large dataset but I let it run for an hour and it never gave me an output.

Comment: what is "a large dataset"? 100Tb? 100Pb? Could you please modify the original question to address the *real* issue? I cannot see how "does not work" is equal to "runs forever".

Comment: Your query works fine on the small sample data that you provided.  See the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75a6b1/2

Comment: 5 Million rows... Maybe I should just let it go as long as it needs, right? Nothing I've done so far has taken that long, so I kind of thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, you are not doing "something wrong". It takes some time to get over all 5M rows, perform some calculations, group them, then perform some more calculations.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll see how that works.

Comment: You may be able to optimize your query, but as zerkms said, doing any amount of grouping/calculations on 5M rows, will take you some time.

Comment: Yes, this will take a while as the non-sargable nature of the query requires the entire table be scanned building a data set consisting of `round(a), b`. Only then can the grouping be done and the `avg(b)` of each group calculated.